# Missing template when rendering a collection using local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, local-variables, missing-template

I have two resources `Category` and `Organization` in my Rails 4 application. I'm struggling with rendering partials combined with local variables.

I have a file `app/views/categories/_category.html.erb`:

```
<li>link_to category.name, category</li>
```

In `app/views/categories/show.html.erb` I can render this partial using

```
<%= render @categories %>
```

To pass a local variable to say, bold-face the current category in the list, I can change the method call to

```
<%= render partial: "category", collection: @categories, as: :category, locals: {active_category: @category} %>
```

So far so good! The code does what I expect it to do.

But I run into problems when I want to do the same thing for my organizations show-view in the file `app/views/organizations/show.html.erb`. The original render call without any local variables works fine, i.e. `render @categories`. The second call however gives me the error

```
Template is missing

Missing partial organizations/_category, application/_category with {
  :locale=>[:en], 
  :formats=>[:html], 
  :variants=>[], 
  :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]
}. 

 Searched in: 
   * "/home/snail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates" 
   * "/home/snail/work/PROJECTNAME/app/views" 
   * "/home/snail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/app/views" 
   * "/home/snail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
```

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to render the same partial at `app/views/categories/_category.html.erb` you need to change your `render` call for your organization's `show` template.

```
render partial: "categories/category", collection: @categories, ...
```

The `app/views/organizations/show.html.erb` template will otherwise look for a file at `app/views/organizations/_category.html.erb`.

Comment: Sigh, I know I tried to do this but I must have done it on the the Category-view or something. Anyhow, now it works. Thanks!